# Subfigure numbering style in referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I am writing and article using latex with several subfigures, when ever I reference the sub figure using `\ref` it appears as `1a`.

How can I change the style of subfigure in `\ref` to look like `1-a`

Comment: Also check out \subref from the subcaption package (page 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Roboticist answer, I needed to modify the command he added to suite my needs, as I have failed to mention in my question that I am using `polyglossia` for Arabic language

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure - \thesubfigure\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

And the 
`\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}` line is not needed as I need letters instead of numbers for sub figures.

Answer (score 2):

I would first reformat the caption label of each subfigure from the default case to `(subfigureNumber)`.

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}
```

Then, the labels can be adapted to what you'd like, say, `(figureNumber-subfigureNumber)`.

```
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure-\arabic{subfigure}\expandafter\@gobble}
```

Thus, the complete assembly below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure-\arabic{subfigure}\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Caption 1}\label{a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Caption 2}\label{b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
Subfigures are \ref{a} and \ref{b}.
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]